# UIPickerView spinning does not stop in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios5, uipickerview

I'm having some problems with an `UIPickerView`. Its delegate method :

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
     didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

is not called when the user taps on the row below the selected one.

The picker animate and place the "touched" row in the middle of the picker but it's spinning doesn't stops(it continue to move about 1px up and 1px down) and the delegate method is not called.

Is there anyone who had the same problem and has a solution for this?

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow1:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
CGFloat pickerRowRectHeight = PICKER_ROW_HEIGHT;

if (!view) 
{
    CGFloat rectWidth = 300;

    CGRect viewRect = !component ? CGRectMake(0, 0, rectWidth, pickerRowRectHeight) : CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, pickerRowRectHeight);
    view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect] autorelease];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake(32 , 0, rectWidth-12, pickerRowRectHeight);
    CGFloat fontSize = FONT_SIZE;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 7, 16, 16);
    imageView.backgroundColor = [ UIColor clearColor];
    imageView.tag = IMAGE_TAG;
    [view addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect];
    label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
    label.tag = LABEL_TAG;          
    [view addSubview:label];
    [label release];
} 



UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:LABEL_TAG];
label.text = [[someArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"title"];
UIImageView *leftImg = (UIImageView*) [view viewWithTag:IMAGE_TAG];
NSData *dataUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[someArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"icon"]]];
if (dataUrl!=nil) {
    leftImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData: dataUrl];
}
else
{
    leftImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[someArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"icon"]];
}


view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

return view;}
```

Comment: I have not had any problem like this one before but I use pickerView a lot. Does your picker vibrate up and down non stop? Or did it go a little above/below and stopped. post more of your code here. Also, make sure that you set up the delegates in .h file and assign delegate to self.

Comment: If the picker is filled up and user selects the row exactly below the center it animates and moves the selected row up and starts "shaking". If the row below center is selected again it works just fine. I forgot to mention that after every selection all the components are reloaded (if the  delegate is called).

Comment: First of all, post more code on from your project. One thing to check is make sure that nothing is hovering over the view. It seems like you made a custom label on your picker. This could cover up other label in the same picker. If that does not work, please post the codes related to your UIPickerView.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you assigned picker view delegate,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

pickerView.delegate = self;
...
```

Comment: Yes delegate is set, it is called when user selects the second row below the center. It works when the first/last row is selected but not for second/forth(has 5 visible rows). And it happens only on iOs 5. In iOs 4 or 3 it works just fine.

Comment: Only some labels are changing the text and a server request is made. And based on the server response the picker is filled again. Something like picker is filled with years, when you select an year is sent to server and server returns some events that will refill the picker. When an event is selected it is sent to server and other events are returned and so on..